# Cannot resolve class com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView

Tags: android, xml

```
 <com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
                android:id="@+id/calendarView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />
```

```
buildscript{
    repositories{
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
        maven (url ="https://jitpack.io")
    }
    dependencies{
//  Hilt dependency
        classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1")
    }
}
```

```
 implementation("com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3")
    implementation("com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.1.1")
```

why can not using com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView, please help to solve this error for me. thanks you!

Comment: post the stacktrace log

Comment: Have you completed the gradle sync post adding the library?

Comment: Yes already added , but it still error

Comment: Post the log or screenshot of the error

Comment: <com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
                android:id="@+id/calendarView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp" /> , it undefined xml Cannot resolve class com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView

Comment: kindly add a screenshot of the gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have the following error syncing with gradle: `Failed to resolve: com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3`

Please try moving `maven (url ="https://jitpack.io")` either to `settings.gradle` (if it has `dependencyResolutionManagement` section):

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    ...
    repositories {
        ...
        maven (url ="https://jitpack.io")
    }
}
```

or to the `allprojects/repositories` section of the top-level `build.gradle` otherwise:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven (url ="https://jitpack.io")
    }
}
```

Comment: @LORSHIM if it worked, could you please mark as accepted?